# implementing indexOf in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm going through the Learn You a Haskell tutorial and attempted to modify the `elem'` function from the [section on Recursion](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion).

The original `elem'` function is:

```
elem' :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem' a [] = False
elem' a (x:xs)
    | a == x    = True
    | otherwise = a `elem'` xs
```

My `indexOf` function is:

```
indexOf :: (Eq a, Integral s) => a -> [a] -> s -> s
indexOf _ [] _ = -1
indexOf a (x:xs) s
    | a == x    = s
    | otherwise = indexOf a xs s+1
```

The function should return either the index of the element in the list, or `-1` if the element is not found.

At the end of my `.hs` file I test the function with:

```
main = putStrLn(show(indexOf 7 [1,2,3] 0))
```

The function works correctly for finding values that appear in the list. However, for the test written above, instead of returning `-1`, it prints `2`. The return value seems to always be the list length minus one.

After encountering the edge condition (empty list), I would expect the `-1` return value to propagate all the way back upwards through the call stack. Where's my mistake?

Comment: Work through a simple example by hand and you'll see why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a precedence problem. Function application binds more tightly than `(+)`, so the `otherwise` case is being parsed as `(index' a xs s) + 1`.

Answer (score 3):

There is one simple change you could make to the example above, which would be almost guaranteed to fix your bug.  Change the return type to `Maybe a`, and return `Nothing` upon failure.  While this alone won't fix your bug, it gives the compiler enough information that it will lead you down the correct path that you will be able to fix it yourself.

Returning `-1` on failure is a very "c" thing to do, and it is error prone.  In your case, the compiler is confusing `-1` with an actual array index, which can be added to as you go back up through the recursive calls.  (I can see that this was not your intention from the signature, but this is how the compiler interpreted what you have done).

(One added advantage- Once you master the art of using correct types, you will soon realize how hard it is to work with functions of the type `a->Maybe b`, or more generally `a->m b`, where `m` is some wrapper type....  This will bring you to the doorstep of understanding what and why we use monads).

Comment: Indeed. Replacing elem with indexOf in the first place feels like an iterative procedural kind of decision rather than a functional one. I worry that a lot of inefficient !! is on the way.